# Angular 2 custom sync validate on value change of property

Tags: angular, validation

I have a angular 2 reactive form with few validations. One field must validate on property change.
My form is as follows.

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(24), forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)]],
      phoneNumber: [null, [this.phoneNumberValidator.bind(this)]],
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]]

    });
```

Custom validate method is as follows

```
phoneNumberValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (!this.isPhoneNumberValid) {
          resolve({
            'phoneNumber': true
          })
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      }, 1000);
    })
  }
}
```

**this.isPhoneNumberValid** is changing according to value change of phone number

But form is not validate as expected.
`this.myForm.get('phoneNumber').errors.phoneNumber` is not giving any value.

My html is as follows

```
<input type="text" formControlName="phoneNumber">

  <div *ngIf="myForm.get('phoneNumber').errors && myForm.get('phoneNumber').errors.phoneNumber">
    Invalid Phone number
  </div>
```

Comment: This seems to be an async validator. If I am right, you would need to pass this validator as the third argument of your formControl. 
phoneNumber: ['', [], [async.validator]].

Comment: Sorry I've missed it, Result is same as usual with this change also :( .